# how to avoid loosing state between components conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to create a form which has two steps/tabs. User can go back and forth. Each step/tab has input boxes. This is how my steps look like:

```
    //components/ProductDetail.js
    const ProductDetail = forwardRef(({ data }, ref) => {
        const [productData, setProductData] = useState({})
    return (
        <Form.Input defaultValue={productData.title} name="title" onChange={handleChange} />
          )
    }

    //components/ProductMetadata.js
    const ProductMetadata = forwardRef(({ data }, ref) => {
        const [productMetadata, setProductMetadata] = useState({})
    return (
        <Form.Input defaultValue={productMetadata.tag} name="tag" onChange={handleChange} />
          )
    }
```

This is how I am displaying them based on which `Step` user clicks on:

```
//displayproduct.js

    const MyProduct = ({ user, data }) => {
        const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState("info")
    
        function handleStepClick(e) {
            const { name } = e.target;
            setCurrentStep(name)
        }
    
    
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Step.Group widths={2}>
                    <Step active={currentStep === "info"} name="info" onClick={handleStepClick} >
                        <Step.Content>
                            <Step.Title>Product Information</Step.Title>
                        </Step.Content>
                    </Step>
                    <Step name="metadata" active={currentStep === "metadata"} onClick={handleStepClick}>
                        <Step.Content>
                            <Step.Title>Product Metadata</Step.Title>
                        </Step.Content>
                    </Step>
                </Step.Group>
                {currentStep == "info" ? <ProductDetail data={data} ></ProductDetail> : <ProductMetadata data={data} ></ProductMetadata>}
            </React.Fragment>
    
        )
    };
    export default MyProduct;
```

This works fine for the most part but when user changes steps back and forth, data gets reinitialized and they loose whatever they had entered previously in those text boxes. I am pretty sure this is happening because the components gets rerendered when user clicks on each step.

How do I avoid loosing data when user goes back and forth the steps?

Comment: Consider refactoring using xstate and storing the data in the xstate context. That way when the state changes, your component can draw the context that was stored the last time the user was in that state. See more info on state management with xstate here: https://xstate.js.org/docs/. If you are interested in this, let me know and I can put together a MWE to get you started.

Comment: updates state with the new value user enters in the textbox.

Comment: Ok. I think I have to save the state when user changes the tab and use that when user goes back to that tab.